# Processing VisaCheckout Payment With Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

i've integration VisaCheckout with Stripe, in testmode is ok but in live gives me JS's error:

**Error Message**

[image: Image1]

**Js of VisaCheckout**

[image: Image2]

And the page stay freezing, no clickable.

**Edit: Code**

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 30px; position: absolute;">
            <img alt="Visa Checkout" class="v-button" role="button" src="https://secure.checkout.visa.com/wallet-services-web/xo/button.png">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.secure.checkout.visa.com/checkout-widget/resources/js/integration/v1/sdk.js"></script>

            <div class="visa-checkout-more">
                <a class="v-learn" data-locale="es_MX" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; display: block; color: #003ea9; font: 14px \'Open Sans Condensed\',sans-serif; margin-left: 65px; cursor: pointer;" aria-label="Aprender sobre Visa Checkout">
                    Conozca más
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: First, insert your [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question!  
Second, what's the value of `message[1]`?

Comment: Are you using your publishable keys or your test keys in production?

Comment: @Jake publishable key

Comment: Oh, sorry, you'll need to use both publishable and secret keys, I meant are you using your live or test keys. (which would be marked as `pk_live_` or `pk_test_`) And, I should add that you should be cautious not to share them in code you may provide.